# Change the default NetBeans debugger?

Tags: java, netbeans, debugging

Is there a way to change the default java debugger in NetBeans 6.8 ?
After a few hours of work ( not debug! ), debugging becomes really slow! It takes minutes for the variables to load. ( the machine i am using is not that weak ).

Cheers, Ivan

Comment: This sounds more like a resource leak rather than a problem with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your machine is swapping, not that the debugger is broken.  Under Linux use iostat and vmstat to see what goes on.  Under Windows use the Task Manager to check page faults.

Comment: Please note that vmstat gives more information if you ask it to get multiple samples with a time interval.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `vmstat X Y` like `vmstat 1 10` which gives you 10 samples with a second inbetween.  It appears, however, that the system _is_ swapping at the last snapshot.

Comment: ok, what should i do? (i can give you a screen of "vmstat 1 10" tomorrow)

Comment: You could also consider upgrading to Netbeans 6.9.  Perhaps even tell the Netbeans launcher to allocate more memory.   I think that will help.